# Laravel session expiration on Carbon::setTestNow()

Tags: laravel, session, cookies, php-carbon

I'm using `Carbon::setTestNow()` for testing purpose on laravel 4.2 project and all the time when I make next refresh after the method call where I used `Carbon::setTestNow()` system log me out. 
It happens because session cookie expiration date sets to `Carbon::setTestNow(`) date. How can I override that because it's annoying to make login again all the time. Thanks, hope some one can help me to find some solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just come to the same situation and here's the result:

The "official way" is to extend the `Illuminate\Session\Middleware::addCookieToResponse` or `::getCookieLifetime`

But I find it's quite complicated and bloated.
Come to a simple solution:

Check if the provided mock time is from the past, override the session.lifetime if needed, here's the codeblock I added into `app/start/global.php`

```
// Set mock time if requested
if ( ! empty($_GET['mocktime'])) {
    try {
        $real_time = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
        $mock_time = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($_GET['mocktime']);

        \Carbon\Carbon::setTestNow($mock_time);

        $diff_min = $real_time->diffInMinutes($mock_time);
        if ($diff_min > 0) {
            // requested mock time is from the pass
            $org_lifetime = Config::get('session.lifetime');
            Config::set('session.lifetime', $diff_min + $org_lifetime);
        }

    } catch (Exception $ex){
        Log::warning('Mocktime requested but unable to set: '.$ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

As this answer is coming late, hope it can help someone later.

Comment: Make almost the same workaround, thanks man for the answer. Hope it will helpful for other

Answer (score 0):

In my case, simply setting the **.env SESSION_LIFETIME** variable to a few years was enough to resolve the issue.

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=999999999
```

My session stopped working out of the blue one month after my setTestNow() date, because I have had my SESSION_LIFETIME set to be one month.